# How to prevent auto-install of Bootstrap (and dependencies) in MVC 5 scaffolding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

When I create a new ASP.net MVC 5 project and add a view via scaffolding from a controller's action, Visual Studio always adds the Nuget package for Bootstrap and its dependencies (e.g. jQuery). Most of the time I find that this is pretty redundant and most of the time I find myself removing it.

Is there an option I can specify when creating a project? or is there a Visual Studio option somewhere that will stop Bootstrap from being installed via view scaffolding? or perhaps let me create my own template to work from?

Comment: This behavior ranges from annoying to very invasive. It does not occur just when creating a new project, but whenever the template decides that Bootstrap, jQuery, and Modernizr are "missing" from the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few options that are available and that will satisfy your needs with varying degrees of overhead.

**Use the default template and remove Bootstrap**

- Right-click your project's `References` and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
- Find the packages that you don't want and Uninstall them.

This will solve the issue of Visual Studio restoring the files when you build, but does not permanently alter the default template.  These dependencies are installed via NuGet, so just deleting the css/js will not remove the dependency your project has on Bootstrap, just the downloaded files.  When NuGet does a package restore it is re-downloading the files you deleted, correctly restoring the dependency.

**Export and re-import the default template**

This is basically saving a modified copy of the default template and importing it as a new/different template.  This does not modify the default template.

Similarly to the first suggestion, start a new project with the normal defaults and then uninstall everything you don't want, adjust the HTML and get things the way you want a default MVC template to be.

After this is done you can export the modified project as a new template following the directions for [Customizing Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx).

**Manually edit the default Visual Studio template**

This will permanently modify the default template.

Default templates are stored in `VSINSTALLDIR\Common7\IDE`.   We're looking for the `WebTemplates` folder.  The folder I used for testing with Visual Studio 2015 (replace `14.0` with `12.0` if using 2013) was located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\MVC\CSharp\1033\MvcBasicApplicationv5.0`

- Navigate to this folder.
- Open the `MvcBasicApplication.cshtml.14.vstemplate` file.
- Look for the `<WizardData><packages>` node
- Here you can remove the default dependencies so that they will not be installed when creating a new project.
- With Bootstrap gone, the html markup will be busted, so you may want to also edit the appropriate files in the `Views` folder to accomidate.

Comment: Good info. What I've seen (and what prompted me to put a bounty on this question) is that Bootstrap/dependencies *and* the default _Layout.cshtml will sometimes be re-added automatically when creating a view. It doesn't matter if the project is new or many months old. Thankfully it doesn't happen all the time, but I can't pinpoint why (I don't have package restore enabled, and even if I did, the packages were removed). Starting with a clean template should eliminate the problem in new projects; I'm curious if it will fix my existing misbehaving projects.

Comment: Regardless of the package restore setting, is Boostrap or something that is dependent on it still listed in your packages.config?

Comment: this is what i have been looking for ages

Comment: This answer is about creating a new project. The OP asks about the packages that are added when you add a view via scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe take a look ate this article:
[Creating a Custom Scaffolder for Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx)