# Mvc scaffolding without bootstrap classes

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a view without bootstrap classes. I set options as below:

[image]

Although the bootstrap script is not added to the view, it still creates elements with bootstrap classes. How can I create views without bootstrap classes?

A part of the created code:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Soyad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Soyad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Soyad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any option to create a template with empty CSS (bootstrap) classes?

Comment: You have selected *Create* template. You should select `Empty` template

Comment: @AdilMammadov, Is there option to create template with empty classes

Comment: What do you mean *template with empty classes*? If you choose *Empty* template you can select model (strongly typed view), but no code will be generated for you inside this view

Comment: @AdilMammadov, you can see what the template is from above image. I mean empty css class

Comment: I am sorry, I got you wrong. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32340691/1380428) may help

Comment: @AdilMammadov, thx for your help

Comment: you can edit the T4 templates that will generate your  views, check this article https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/